# Why are all the fields in Configure VM disabled for my VM?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vmware-server, configuration

I loading a VM that worked fine in VMWare Player into VMWare Server 2.02. 
It will not run. It is currently suspended. I get an error message indicating that this OS is not supported on my host OS when I try to launch it.

The buttons for shut down and restart are not enabled.
I tried Configure VM, but all the fields are disabled.

It is a Windows 7 Home Premium (x86) VM running under Windows XP.

I thought that was an acceptable combination, but I get a message stating that it is not supported.

What is going on? (thanks)

Comment: @mailq, post this as an answer so I can give you a vote! :)

Answer (score 1):

The system is running. You can't configure a running system. Shutdown the guest, configure the guest and restart the guest.